# Is there a way to work with multiple files in node when making a discord bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm making a discord bot, I can't understand how you're supposed to make multiple commands in one file.

For example, I was doing this ( I know it doesn't work )

```js
const Discord = require(`discord.js`);
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'MyToken';

require('./moderator.js');

bot.login(token);
```

And then there would be another file named ( moderator.js ) which had the moderator commands.
Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should assign your file to a const in the scope, but if u want to have 2 files how had the same name I dont think u can do it, I hope I answered to ur question ✌️

There is a code I have quickly done

```
const Discord = require(`discord.js`);
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'MyToken';

let a = require('./moderator.js');

bot.login(token);

console.log(a.command1)
// should u return "delete_messages"

// In ur moderator.js file :

function command1(Ur Params){
// Do what ever u do
        let perm1 ="delete_messages"
        return perm 1;


}



// at the END of moderator.js


return(command1);
```